# Kinit autentication does not create klist ticket

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

I´ve been trying to connect to a HDFS server protected by Kerberos for days.

I alterady have have Kerberos for windows installed here. And it shows me the valid/active ticket.

[image: Kerberos 4.1 windows desktop GUI]

But as I run 'Klist' on prompt, I see no tickets

[image: CMD PROMPT Klist]

If I run Kinit on prompt, it asks for my password and returns 'Authenticated to Kerberos v5' but still does not show me any klist ticket.

[image: CMD PROMPT KINIT]

If I create a new tickt, using prompt or Kerberos GUI, it comes back showing me an active/valid ticket, but klist still does not.

I am trying to connect to hdfs using KerberosClient, but as I connect, somehow it does not "see" my active ticked (as klist too), so I got a connection denial.

I´ve setup the KRB5_CONFIG and KRB5CCNAME system variables to the folder exposed above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has two Kerberos libraries (MIT KfW & Windows SSPI) and two different `klist` tools:

1. the Windows `klist.exe`, which only shows the Windows LSA in-memory ticket cache that will be used by "Windows native" SSPI-based applications;
2. the MIT Kerberos `klist.exe`, which shows the file-based $KRB5CCNAME ticket cache that will be used by MIT "gssapi32.dll" GSSAPI-based applications.
3. (sometimes also the Java JRE `klist.exe` as well!)

If your HDFS client uses $KRB5CCNAME (e.g. if it uses GSSAPI via gssapi32.dll), then you need to run the MIT KfW `klist.exe` specifically. Use `where.exe kinit` to find out where it's located, then run it by full path.

On the other hand, if your HDFS client uses SSPI, then MIT KfW won't help you much – it can access tickets in the "MSLSA:" cache, but as far as I know it cannot put new tickets there. (It *is* possible to easily make SSPI acquire tickets for non-AD Kerberos services, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: I´ve noticed that my MIT desktop GUI shows me two tickets. One of them is the MSLSA!
Thanks.